# Can I delete the Apple_KernelCoreDump partition in High Sierra?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, high-sierra

In MacOS High Sierra's Disk Utility, the partition is listed as Kernel Core Dump Storage (655MB). Its type is `Apple_KernelCoreDump` in the result of `diskutil list`. There is also a description, "You can not remove this volume because the previous volume can not be resized." However, if the partition is simply a collection of core dump files, it should be safe to remove the partition.

It does not take too much space but it is in between some free space and the partition I want to increase its size. There is no other easy ways to resize it unless I remove the `Apple_KernelCoreDump` partition.

[image: partitions in disk utility]

Comment: The screenshot is almost useless. Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show disk0`. And when apfs is used the output of `diskutil ap list`.

Comment: @klanomath The first command results in `Operation not permitted` and the second command shows something like:
<pre>
+-- Container disk1
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2
    +-> Volume disk1s1 (Macintosh HD)
    +-> Volume disk1s2 (Preboot)
    +-> Volume disk1s3 (Recovery)
    +-> Volume disk1s4 (VM)
</pre>

Comment: By the way, I think the structure of my disk is unrelated to the issue. I just wonder if the kernel core dump partition, which was automatically created by High Sierra, is safe to be removed.

Comment: If a description like "You can not remove this volume because the previous volume can not be resized." is added, the structure of the disk is indeed important...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally taken the risk to delete `Apple_KernelCoreDump` partition. I did a full Time Machine backup in an external storage and then rebooted into recovery mode. From the Disk Utility there, I successfully deleted the `Apple_KernelCoreDump` partition in between two partitions. So far, there have been no problem.

Comment: did you restart your machine after deleting this partition?

Comment: @dark_ruby To get back into the normal mode, I think a reboot is required

Comment: what do you mean `"normal mode"` ?, did you have to delete partition in `"non normal mode"` ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, I did it in recovery mode.