# I deleted partition and now I don't see the free space in Disk Utility

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

so I do have a problem. I create a backup partition, by mistake via Time Machine on my disk. I wanted to deleted 'cause it was above half of my memory. I couldn't, so I type some commands I found on internet, and now I don't have that partition. But I don't see any free space in Disk Utility. [image: DiskUtility]

[image: Partition]

I'm Pole so that's why language is polish. Anyway problem is that my disk is 500 GB, but I can see only 200GB claim, by "MacOSX". How can I add those almost 300GB space to "MacOSX" partition? I tried using Stellar:[image: StellarPartitionManager]

So I know it's possible, but i don't have money on full version of the program. So I ask You for help. How can I do it for free?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301884/how-can-i-merge-primary-apfs-partition-with-other-empty-apfs-partition/325322#325322

Comment: What OS version are you running?  Hard to tell with the polish, but it looks like your disk is still using HFS+ format.

Comment: I'm using Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 1):

Have you try these steps to fix your issue:

```
$ diskutil list
```

It will list your physical drive detail. Note the drive name for unallocated space.

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" %noformat% /dev/disk0s3
```

Assuming your volume is named disk0s3

Next, resize your APFS Container

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

With value zero at the end, diskutil will automatically claim all available free space.

It should be fine and then you can re-setup macOS from Recovery mode.

Comment: I'm using Sierra, when I try to use it on my disk "MacOSX" it says "The target disk is in use by Core Storage as a Physical Volume; use diskutil coreStorage verbs". After using with coreStorage "diskutil: did not recognize coreStorage verb "eraseVolume"; type "diskutil coreStorage" for a list
"

Comment: @Nilille: Check this then https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154964/resizing-or-expanding-a-corestorage-volume

Comment: when I type diskutil cs list, I get this
"No CoreStorage logical volume groups found" I've tried doing this in recovery mode, as the tutorial says. My diskutil list looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/CFHy5JL . Another question should I expand disk0s2?

Comment: Do you have any solution for that? Please?

Comment: Share me your screenshot of diskutil with the detail view. I will try my best to help you. Which macOS version do you have in your system?

Comment: [link] (https://imgur.com/a/2h5fyMa) I'm using Sierra 10.12.6. Tell me if I have to use a different command, 'cause that commands are all I can think of detail view. Hope to hear from you soon, and thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: are you still there?