# How do I bring back my lost space after trying to merge APFS partitions?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, apfs, macos

[How can I merge primary APFS partition with other empty APFS partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301884/how-can-i-merge-primary-apfs-partition-with-other-empty-apfs-partition?newreg=97b963101d004f74865b8938c140cab1)

After reading and following the above, I got stuck on the  eraseVolume "Free Space" and now that space seems irrevocably lost. Did apfs resizeContainer but got Error: -69743: The new size must be different than the existing size and it seems that my 2TB physical drive can recognise only 999.4GB...
[image]

any help?

Comment: mac OS Catalina btw

Comment: Are you trying to do this whilst booted from it? It won't let you saw off the branch you're sitting on.

Comment: Can you restart the Mac and then post the output from the commands `diskutil list disk0` and `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset`? Edit your question and place the output there.